# Wordpress loop not returning more then 1 post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function to get posts by category i passed a parameter to show about 4 posts per page but in return i am only getting 1 post

```
function get_recent_events($atts){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'posts' => 1,
), $atts));

    query_posts(array('category_name' => 'Events', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
  if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $output = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br />';
   endwhile;
   endif;

    wp_reset_query();
   return $output;
}
add_shortcode("recent_events", "get_recent_events");
```

and on page it is called by using shortcode with a parameter [recent_events posts="4"] it should return 4 posts but I am getting 1 can anyone help me out with this concern

Comment: and what about `'posts' => 1` which you using in your code?

Comment: using for default if users skips and not place the post parameter so by default it would set to 1 it is okay to use like this ?

Comment: Never use `query_posts`

Comment: I saw in wordpress codex so that is why i used any other option if you can suggest me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=4' );
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working when I am trying to do the same thing within ul and li it is bringing 4 posts query_posts('category_name = Events&posts_per_page='.$posts);

Comment: not workin I dont know why it is happening but when i wrap the output in  ul li it  it is returning 1 it does effect ?

Comment: var dump result from query and see how much post is return